# "Get opened tabs URLs" extension of chrome integration

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I  have downloaded [Get opened tabs URLs](https://github.com/cbenz/Get-opened-tabs-URLs-Chrome-extension) extension and I am trying to integrate with my website,
like "copy to clipboard" functionality I want paste functionality

i.e. when I clicked "copy to clipboard" then it should paste where I want.

Is any have any idea how to access it work out with application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Chrome extension API. You can't use it on regular websites, only from Chrome extensions and [packaged apps](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html).

Comment: Is there any way to find a url of open tabs of browser window  through   our application or website.